# Lead nano carbon batteries over Lithium?

Tags: batteries, off-grid

The person quoting me on an off grid solution is suggesting lead nano carbon batteries instead of Lithium Ion or ordinary lead acid.

Is this technology mature enough yet?  And is this now the way to go for off-grid solutions?

**Update:** This the [link](http://en.naradapower.com/index.php/products/info/14?ctype=46) I was given by the supplier. These are Chinese batteries that don't mention **nano** at all.  This seems to be technology which allows the battery to operate at partial state of charge without the same risks of hard sulphation

> The ALC is being tested as a replacement for the classic starter battery in start-stop applications and in 48V micro and mild hybrid systems. Rapid charging on regenerative breaking is a decisive advantage with these batteries, a task that is difficult to achieve with regular lead acid. Although larger and heavier than Li-ion, the ALC is low-cost, operates at subfreezing temperatures and does not need active cooling — advantages Li-ion cannot claim. Unlike regular lead acid, lead carbon can operate between 30 and 70 percent state-of-charge without fear of becoming sulfated. The ALC is said to outlive the regular lead acid battery, but the negative is a rapid voltage drop on discharge, resembling that of a supercapacitor.

http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/new_lead_acid_systems

Comment: The first several google results for "lead nano carbon batteries" point to stores or marketing. I suspect this may be a marketing term more than a technical one... do you know the manufacturer or model, to get a few more details? Also the main advantage of lithium-ion is power density, which typically isn't worth the added cost in an off-grid situation (unless you're carrying the batteries up a mountain on foot).

Comment: They don't give me a manufacturer ... http://greensparksolar.co.nz/Off-Grid.php I think they're talking about this technology https://chargedevs.com/newswire/solving-the-energy-density-challenge-with-single-wall-carbon-nanotubes/

Comment: Another battery type you may want to investigate is vanadium redox (also known as vanadium flow) battery.

Comment: Ok, they gave me this link http://en.naradapower.com/index.php/products/info/14?ctype=46 lead carbon batteries

Comment: Maybe the same as this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraBattery

Comment: How many local businesses or contractors can you find who are willing to service these batteries?

Comment: The importer will warranty them for three years